# Laravel 5.4 named route usage with route parameter

Tags: php, laravel, routes, request, laravel-5.4

I have an upragate laravel 5.2 to 5.4
and my named routes not working.

that web routes for example

```
 Route::get('tempURL2/get/{filename}', [
    'as' => 'getentry', 'uses' => 'temaYukle@get']);
```

getting route name and show parameters in blade

```
<a href="{{url("tempURL2/get")}}/{{$entry->fileName}}">{{$entry->orgFileName}}</a>
```

html result :

> `<a href="http://localhost:8521/tempURL2/get/phpd089B0.zip">downloads.zip</a>`

this request http headers:

> Request URL:http://localhost:8521/tempURL2/get/phpCDA4.tmp.zip
>
> Request Method:GET
>
> Status Code:404 Not
>
> Found Remote Address:[::1]:8521

Comment: So basically requests to `somesite.com` get converted to requests to `localhost:8521`?

Comment: @apokryfos sorry It was not the one I wanted to tell. Updating question

Comment: It's still unclear. The HTML references `phpd089B0.zip` but the request references `phpCDA4.tmp.zip` it's impossible to tell if that's part of the problem or if that's another omission.

Comment: There is a helper called `route()`.. that's made specifically for using with named routes..
use it instead of `url()`

Comment: @apokryfos 'get/', then the next up to '/' must be taken as a parameter. What is the content of the important 404 error

Comment: Try adding a `dd("reached")` inside `temaYukle@get` to see if it's called at all. If it is then the problem is not the laravel upgrade.

Comment: I try to try but [link](http://imgur.com/a/wDP2w) this screen. The interesting remote server works as it should be. Why it is more normal for the server not to worked.